# How to uninstall custom app from shopify store via API call

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I was trying to uninstall custom app from shopify store via API call .

I have tried multiple request to uninstall the custom App:

https://${shop}/admin/oauth/access_scopes/${appId}.json

https://${shop}/admin/api/2023-01/applications/${appId}/uninstall.json

https://${shop}/admin/api/2023-01/app/installations/${appId}.json

https://${shop}/admin/api/2021-09/app/installations/current.json

https://${apiKey}:${apiSecret}@${shop}/admin/api/2021-09/applications/${appId}.json

https://${shop}/admin/api/2023-01/applications_installed/${appId}.json

https://${shop}/admin/api/2021-09/applications/${appId}/api_uninstall.json

Comment: As per my knowledge app install and uninstall need store authorized user interaction, you want do the same using API calls

Comment: Yes, i want to do the same through api call

Comment: There is no way to do the same using api calls